# Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143 while running pig script

Tags: hive, apache-pig

While joining more number of records using pig and loading data in hive, I am getting an error as container exited with a non-zero exit code 143 while running pig script.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

I have tried increasing the number of mappers and reducers individually.

Comment: can you share sample code, or what you have written so far

Comment: check whether using too much memory over the specified in the script